# Counting categorical variables on row in SAS

Tags: sas

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cqlw.png)

I was wondering if it is possible to use data instead of proc to count the number of categorical variables on a row as shown in 'count' example above. This will allow me to further use the data e.g COUNT=1 or COUNT > 1 to check morbidity.

Also will it be possible to then count the number of each diagnosis in the entire data set per patient while accounting for duplicates if there is any? For example there are 3 CB's and 2 AA's in this data set but CB should be 2 because patient 2 had it recorded twice.

Thank you for your time and have a lovely new year.

Comment: post sample data as text and not as image ..

Comment: What have you tried?  Why do you want to use data steps instead proc steps? Why did you add the MYSQL tag?  Are you looking for SAS solution or a MYSQL solution?

Comment: Or is your SAS script connected to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but your could manage your diag using union all  and count distinct

```
selec patient count(distinct diag )
from (
  select patient, diag1 as diag
  from my_table 
  uniona all 
  select patient, diag2
  from my_table 
  uniona all 
  select patient, diag3
  from my_table 
  uniona all 
  select patient, diag4
  from my_table 
) t
group by patient
```

or simply union and count

```
selec patient count(diag )
from (
  select patient, diag1 as diag
  from my_table 
  uniona
  select patient, diag2
  from my_table 
  uniona 
  select patient, diag3
  from my_table 
  uniona 
  select patient, diag4
  from my_table 
) t
group by patient
```

Answer (score 0):

The image indicates that for each row you want a count of the number of columns with non-missing values.  Additionally, you apparently have some way to do this using a `PROC` step, but would like to know how using a `DATA` step.

In DATA step you can count the number of non-missing values indirectly using `CMISS`, or directly using `COUNTC` against a constructed value:

```
data have;
  attrib pid length=8 diag1-diag4 length=$5;
  input pid & diag1-diag4;
  datalines;
1  AA J9 HH6 .
2  CB . . CB
3  J10 AA CB J10 
4  B B . F90 .
5  J10 . . .
6  . . . .
run;

data have_with_count;
  set have;
  count = 4 - cmiss (of diag1-diag4);
  count_way2 = countc(catx('~', of diag1-diag4, 'SENTINEL'), '~');
run;
```

In order to work again MySQL data source you will also need a libref that connects you to that remote data server.

#### Added

Counting distinct values across a row can be accomplished using a `hash` or `sortc`.  Consider this example that sorts a copy of the row data (as an array) and counts the unique values within:

```
data want;
  set have;
  array diag diag1-diag4;
  array v(4) $5 _temporary_;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(diag);
    v(_n_) = diag(_n_);
  end;
  call sortc(of v(*));
  uniq = 0;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(v);
    if missing(v(_n_)) then continue;
    if uniq = 0 then 
      uniq + 1;
    else
      uniq + ( v(_n_) ne v(_n_-1) );
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Richard's dummy data to count number of diagnosis and unique number of diagnosis:

```
data want;
   set have;
   array var diag:;
   length temp $30.;
   call missing(diag_num);
   do over var;
      if not missing(var) then do;
         diag_num+1;
         temp=ifc(whichc(var, temp),temp,catx(' ',temp,var));
      end;
   end;
   unique_diag=countw(temp);
   drop temp;
run;
```